# Bizarre photograph from an airshow

Tags: airshow

I ran into this picture [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AIR14_(15306814355).jpg), entirely by accident.

[image: Picture]

I recognise 121.5MHz as the emergency frequency, which seems apt for this particular photo.

This looks like two aircraft crashing into each other, but apparently it's from an air show and there's no mention of a crash. What's going on here? Put bluntly, it looks like the F/A-18 is humping a chopper. Are my eyes being deceived by camera magic, or is this an incredibly bizarre mid-air stunt?

Comment: …and that's why you avoid overlapping subjects when shooting with a telephoto lens.

Comment: While the print is 2D, the world is 3D. Is that enough for an explanation?

Comment: Not enough to justify a full answer but the “STBY 121.5” marking on the drop tank is for air defense intercept duty to notify pilots to tune their radio to Guard for further instructions.

Comment: This question seems to have attracted both positive and negative votes. That would suggest this is at least half decent as it is but some of us want to see it improved. Any feedback, as always, from the downvoters is welcome...

Comment: RE - "Not enough to justify a full answer but the “STBY 121.5” marking on the drop tank is for air defense intercept duty to notify pilots to tune their radio to Guard for further instructions. "  btw that has already been the subject of a question/ answer on this site before, possibly involving this exact photo, or at least an aircraft of same type in same markings.

Comment: Bit sad that this got downvoted so much, since it's a valid question even if the answer might seem obvious to those of you more familiar with aircraft photography. (I don't actually care, it just seems like poor practice for SE)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, this is a trick played on you by your eye and the telephoto lens used to take this picture. More on this phenomenon here:

[Photograpy Stack Exchange - What does it really mean that telephoto lenses "flatten" scenes?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/18185/96150)

Your perception is not entirely without merit. Here is a comparison of side views of the two aircraft in question, [Eurocopter Super Puma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurocopter_AS332_Super_Puma) and [F/A-18C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F/A-18_Hornet):
[image]
While this picture might not be entirely accurate, it does show that the two aircraft are quite similar in size. One would think that the Helicopter is huge and the fighter jet is quite compact, but no. Throw into the equation the conversion errors form 2d to 3d inside our brain, and everything goes haywire.

The picture is form a situation where the two aircraft were actually flying in formation, this is a standard performance of Swiss air force, similar performance is shown in this video:

[Youtube - AIR 14 Payerne F/A 18 Hornet, Super Puma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lc0a-EUQeEc)

Comment: Freezing that video at [23s](https://youtu.be/Lc0a-EUQeEc?t=23) gives almost the same shot.  There's no confusion with the video rolling as your brain can interpret the relative distance

Comment: Whoa, a fighter and a helicopter flying in formation, something I had not seen before.

Comment: It's kinda tricky, as the helicopter and the jet will be operating at opposite ends of their speed range. Helo will need to go near max maneuvering speed, while the Hornet will have to fly at relatively high AoA and power setting to maintain level flight.

Comment: Which is why you see a slight nose down attitude on the helicopter and a very nose high attitude on the jet.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! The sizing was really throwing me, along with the weird lack of parallax (presumably because the telephoto lens distorts the parallax).

Comment: @Polynomial [Parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax) isn't what you think it is - there's no parallax in a still image. You need at least two images (or a video), whereby the linear shift of objects from one image to the next is inversely proportional to their distance from the camera. You may be thinking of [depth of field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_of_field).

Comment: @TypeIA oddly enough, parallax can effect non-stereoscopic observations: for example some rifle scopes have parallax adjustment, and the one on my high power scope clearly changes (also) the depth of field of the image when adjusted.

Comment: @Jpe61 It doesn't have to be stereoscopic, it just has to be moving. The parallax adjustment on a scope changes the focal point of the optics relative to the reticule. It does change the DoF, but if you take a snapshot from a particular eyepoint through the scope, there is no movement and therefore no parallax.

Comment: As @TypeIA implies, it's the parallax in the video that blocks the illusion (the word escaped me yesterday)

Comment: @TypeIA Poor phrasing on my part. What I meant is that the subjects being the same (apparent) size, being in equal focus (+ lack of DOF effects), and having no clear difference in motion blur or aberration, all contribute to a distortion of the sense of depth when parallax is lost. Photographs usually retain some clues (e.g. defocus, relative motion blur) that help the eye resolve depth in the absence of actual parallax, particularly in a moving scene, but it seems like telephoto lenses tend to reduce those effects (at least in skilled hands) and obfuscate the depth.